# Why does Forrest always wear a blue shirt?

Tags: forrest-gump

From childhood to adult stage, Forrest Gump is always shown wearing a blue shirt.

Is there any reason?

Comment: His son is also shown wearing the same kind of shirt at the end of the film.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to Collider](https://collider.com/galleries/forrest-gump-behind-the-scenes-facts/):

> Have you ever watched the film and noticed that Forrest sports blue checkers a lot? This wasn’t due to laziness on the wardrobe team’s side; it symbolizes the many transitions in his life. **He wears a different form of a blue checkered shirt in the first scene of each age transition in the film, to signify a change in time.**
>
> The movie ends with Forrest’s son similarly wearing a blue checkered shirt when he is getting onto the bus. **Although the cast and crew from the film have not acknowledged why they did this**, it became a fun Easter egg when it was discovered by fans.